# Including extensive SVG images, too many pages in the pdf?

Tags: graphics, texmaker, svg

I have a lot of svg images I want to include in a TeX-File.

So far I didn't have problems using the `\usepackage{svg}` with `\includesvg`.

However recently I've added a few more layers to the svg-files and now a lot of stuff is missing.

The resulting svg-tex.pdf files now have up to 61 pages and if I look into the svg-tex.pdf_tex files with texmaker I found the culprit: it only goes up to 50 pages:

```
\put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=50]{Sym_9999_svg-tex.pdf}}%
```

Putting the pages in manually like:

```
\put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,**page=51**]{Sym_9999_svg-tex.pdf}}%
```

does work, but would be very time inefficient (I have 100+ svg images) additionally the layers don't have the correct sequence and cover up text sometimes.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

If I open up the svg-image it shows up just fine.

One possibility would be to just export the svgs in one pdf file without the text as extra latex file, but this way I can't add formulas in Tex-Form.

Answer (score 2):

I just found a solution for the problem for anyone interested in it:

Open up the .svg file in inkscape, select all, ungroup them and save.